# Propel Criteria

Tags: symfony1, criteria, propel

I'm trying to create the following statement using Criteria and Propel:

```
AND unix_timestamp(table.last_action) > unix_timestamp(table.last_action) -1800
```

But i don't seem to be able to get it right

```
$kriterien->add(sfGuardUserProfilePeer::LAST_ACTION, 'unix_timestamp(table.last_action)-90', Criteria::GREATER_THEN);
```

`sfGuardUserProfilePeer::LAST_ACTION` is not a unix_timestamp. How can I change it so that it is? I already tried to simply change the value of `LAST_ACTION` in `BasesGuardUserProfilePeer.php` but it threw an error.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The database won't be able to use any indexes to resolve this part of the query since you're needlessly applying functions; you do not need to work with UNIX timestamps to modify dates. `something > something - INTERVAL 1800 SECOND`. Of course, your query as is makes no sense, as a column cannot be greater than itself...

Comment: what? :-)
the query works perfectly fine 
something > something - 1800 seconds is every something between now and half an hour ago

Comment: No, `something > something - 1800` is every row. All numbers are greater than themselves minus some other number. `something > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1800` would be every row between now and half an hour ago.

Comment: yeah, you're right. but does timestamp1 > timestamp2 work with unix_timestamp? because it kinda doesn't....

Comment: ok, i know why (although it doesn't make sense to me).
the query turns out to be     AND sf_guard_user_profile.LETZTE_AKTION > '(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 90 SECOND)'
it works like this
AND sf_guard_user_profile.LETZTE_AKTION > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 90 SECOND). how do i get the ' out?

Comment: @ldrocks - how are you getting on with this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such constant as `Criteria::GREATER_THEN` - perhaps you meant `Criteria::GREATER_THAN`? However if you use that, the second parameter to `add()` must be a string or integer value - trying to use column names or SQL functions won't work.

Instead, try this (obviously you may need to tweak - I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve):

```
$kriterien->add(
    sfGuardUserProfilePeer::LAST_ACTION,
    'unix_timestamp(sf_guard_user_profile.last_action) > 90',
    Criteria::CUSTOM
);
```

Lastly, the `Criteria` approach is deprecated. You don't say what version of Propel you're using (and this detail ought to be in your question) but it is a good idea to be using something recent (1.5 or 1.6) and to migrate to the Query approach instead.